# How to render Symfony Form in Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, symfony-forms, symfony4

I Vue Js beginner and have just started Vue Js with Symfony 4 and I' having trouble with form render in Vue.js .

App.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './Components/App.vue'
import PostForm from './Components/PostForm.vue'

new Vue({

el: '#app',
components: { App },
PostForm
})
```

PostForm.vue

```
<template>

<div>

    <h2 class="text-center">Post</h2>
    <div id="post-form-holder" ref="form">

    </div>
</div>

</template>

<script>

import axios from 'axoios'

export default {

    async mounted(){

        let {data} = await axios.get('/SymVue/post')
        this.refs.form.innerHtml = data.form
    }
}

</script>
```

Controller

```
    /**
*
* @Route("/post", name="post.form")
*/
public function formAction(){

    $form = $this->createForm(PostType::class);

    $view = $this->renderView('vue/form.html.twig',[

        'form' => $form->createView()
    ]);
    return new Response('This is response');

}
```

On running http://localhost:8000/SymVue/post, the browser displays response message 'This is response'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you run http://localhost:8000/SymVue/post then obviously you'll see the response in browser. As Far as I know 2 methods should be there. In your case. The first method will render form in browser and second will create form...

Like this....

```
 /**
 * @Route("/", name="vue", methods={"GET", "POST"})
 */
public function index()
{
    return $this->render('vue/index.html.twig');
}



/**
*
* @Route("/post", name="post.form")
*/
public function formAction(){

    $form = $this->createForm(PostType::class);

    $view = $this->renderView('vue/form.html.twig',[

        'form' => $form->createView()
    ]);
return new Response('This is response');

}
```

And talking about your app.js I guess you have messed up , but anyway you do something like this if you want to render in PostForm.vue. Create post.js in js folder and write following code..

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import PostForm from './Components/PostForm.vue'

new Vue({

    template: '<PostForm />',
    components: { PostForm }

}).$mount('#postForm');
```

And in your PostForm.vue (In your code have made some spelling mistakes)

```
import axios from 'axios'
import 'babel-polyfill'

export default {

    name: 'PostForm',

    async mounted(){

        let {data} = await axios.get('/SymVue/post')            
        this.$refs.form.innerHTML = data.form
    }
}
```

Now going back to Twig Template in your vue/index.html.twig

```
{% block body %}

    <div id="postForm">

        <PostForm />

   </div>

{% endblock %}

    {% block javascripts %}


        <script src="{{ asset('build/postForm.js') }}"></script>

    {% endblock %}
```

Don't forget to add entry in webpack.config.js

```
.addEntry('postForm', './assets/js/post.js')
```

Comment: Thanks, after several try I could do. Actually I got lil confused.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. But how do you handle v-model in this case? Assuming that your inputs should have models like form.user.name, form.user.avatar and these are dynamically generated and returned by Symfony, how do you handle them? Vuejs choke on undefined data.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use VueJs with a Symfony, I'm not suggesting you to pass html code via symfony like in previous answers, you'll mess up application templates and do 1 extra request. You should better create a form as usual in html/vue code and pass csrf code manually. If you still want to generate a form using symfony, just pass it using slots like so:

```
<some-vue-component>
   <div slot="form">
       {{ form(form) }}
   </div>
</some-vue-component>
```

You also can take a look at [small vue component](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-symfony-form) I wrote for such cases to show form errors automatically with a FOSRestBundle. Also you can implement Synchronizer Token Pattern or any other protection type with a connector.

Answer (score 0):

Use the rendered template as Response body. :)

```
$view = $this->renderView('vue/form.html.twig',[

        'form' => $form->createView()
    ]);

 return new JsonResponse(['form' => $view]);
```

Comment: Same even after the change.